# Tentative locks in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, locking

Suppose I'd like to allow parallel execution of some code, but need other code wait for all these operations to finish.

Let's imagine a `softlock` in addition to `lock`:

```
public static class MySimpleCache
{
    private static readonly SynchronizedCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Collection = new SynchronizedCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    public static string Get(string key, Func<string> getter)
    {
        // Allow parallel enumerations here,
        // but force modifications to the collections to wait. 
        softlock(Collection.SyncRoot)
        {
            if (Collection.Any(kvp => kvp.Key == key))
            {
                return Collection.First(kvp => kvp.Key == key).Value;
            }
        }

        var data = getter();

        // Wait for previous soft-locks before modifying the collection and let subsequent softlocks wait
        lock (Collection.SyncRoot)
        {
            Collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, data));
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Is there any design-pattern or language/framework features in C#/.NET to achieve this in a straightforward and reliable fashion, or would one have to implement this from the ground up?

I'm currently limited to .NET 3.5 and I'm mostly interested in the conceptual issue, not so much in other possible collections that might solve the example in itself.

Comment: Sounds like you need [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) which can start off as a reader lock, and be upgraded to a writer lock.

Comment: Your lookup is slightly inefficient, you enumerate twice, you could use `var result = Collection.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key == key); if(result != default(KeyValuePair<string, string>)) { return result.Value; }` and only do the lookup once.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks, that looks very suitable, I'll play around with it.

Comment: Oops != won't work, but i am writing up a answer (with ReaderWriterLockSlim) that will have a fixed version too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Although then I generally could not distinguish between whether the collection does not contain the value, or if the value it contains is null.

Comment: ... and the type of the collection in this example is quite arbitrary.

Comment: @Alex see the P.S. of my answer for a `TryFirst(` that could work if the value of the collection could be null.

Comment: You are asking for Monitor.TryEnter().  The usual hangup is that you *have* to do something reasonable when it returns *false*.  Your snippet isn't up to that task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations like this you can use a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx), it will allow multiple readers until someone wants to write, it then blocks all readers and only allows a single writer through.

```
public static class MySimpleCache
{
    private static readonly SynchronizedCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Collection = new SynchronizedCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    private static readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim Lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public static string Get(string key, Func<string> getter)
    {
        //This allows multiple readers to run concurrently.
        Lock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            var result = Collection.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key == key);
            if (!Object.Equals(result, default(KeyValuePair<string, string>)))
            {
                return result.Value;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Lock.ExitReadLock();
        }


        var data = getter();

        //This blocks all future EnterReadLock(), once all finish it allows the function to continue
        Lock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            Collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, data));
            return data;
        }
        finally
        {
            Lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

However, you may want to check to see while you where waiting to take the write lock someone else may have entered the record in to the cache, in that case you can use a `EnterUpgradeableReadLock()`, this allows unlimited people to be inside `EnterReadLock()` but only a single person can be in the upgrade lock (and there will still be no write locks). The upgrade-able lock is useful when you know you will likely be writing but there is a opportunity to not write.

```
public static class MySimpleCache
{
    private static readonly SynchronizedCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Collection = new SynchronizedCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    private static readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim Lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public static string Get(string key, Func<string> getter)
    {
        //This allows multiple readers to run concurrently.
        Lock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            var result = Collection.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key == key);
            if (!Object.Equals(result, default(KeyValuePair<string, string>)))
            {
                return result.Value;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Lock.ExitReadLock();
        }

        //This allows unlimited EnterReadLock to run concurrently, but only one thread can be in upgrade mode, other threads will block.
        Lock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
        try
        {
            //We need to check to see if someone else filled the cache while we where waiting.
            var result = Collection.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key == key);
            if (!Object.Equals(result, default(KeyValuePair<string, string>)))
            {
                return result.Value;
            }


            var data = getter();

            //This blocks all future EnterReadLock(), once all finish it allows the function to continue
            Lock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                Collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, data));
                return data;
            }
            finally
            {
                Lock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Lock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**P.S.** You mentioned in a comment that the value could be null so `FirstOrDefault()` would not work. In that case use a extension method to make a `TryFirst()` function.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool TryFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, Func<T, bool> predicate, out T result)
    {
        foreach (var item in @this)
        {
            if (predicate(item))
            {
                result = item;
                return true;
            }
        }
        result = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}

//Used like
Lock.EnterReadLock();
try
{
    KeyValuePair<string, string> result;
    bool found = Collection.TryFirst(kvp => kvp.Key == key, out result);
    if (found)
    {
        return result.Value;
    }
}
finally
{
    Lock.ExitReadLock();
}
```